# Extract CMSampleBuffer from HLS video stream on iOS

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, http-live-streaming, cmsamplebuffer

How can I save what `AVPlayer` is currently playing (both video and audio) from Live HLS stream?

I know how to load and play `m3u8` video file using `AVPlayer`.

Please note that the HLS stream is live and not Video on demand so cannot use `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask` In the perfect scenario will get `CMSampleBuffer` objects which can save to file easily. Also `AVPlayerItemOutput` is not entirely an option because I am unable to see how will get the audio channel.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way with AVFoundation to get a hold of the actual HLS stream...other than playing it.

Comment: Any other non AVFoundation way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not possible with the current SDK. I've implemented it using ffmpeg